# How to transfer Mailing from my ID to the ID of the person the form is shared with?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have developed an Appscript which triggers when someone fills up and submits a form.
Upon submission, the script triggers and mails certain contents of the form to the people mentioned in one of the fields in the Form.

This is using a combination of - Google Forms, Google sheets (linked to response of Google Form) and Google Appscript (inserted in the Sheet which is linked to the Form) - such that it is trigerred when the form is submitted.

It sends emails from my ID which is natural.

Now, the problem starts when I share this stack with someone else.
I have shared the entire stack - Form, sheet and script.

I want the mails to be sent from their IDs when they fill the Form. However, the mails are still going from my ID.

I have even transferred ownership - not just the editing right?

I guess the last option is I remove myself from the forms and solely give them the ownership, but I was wondering, is there any work-around to this?

Comment: Have you deployed this in any way? It shouldn't be possible for them to run a script from their account and have it send from your email, unless it has been deployed as a web app or something. Are you sure copies are being made?

Comment: I have not deployed anything - actually I am not able to understand what deployment means. The script currently gets triggered whenever submits the form, so I did not feel the need to deploy. 
How can deployment help? I do not have any website or place where I can deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sharing and Script execution

Lets examine a few scenarios:

1. Sharing a simple script.
2. Sharing a document with a bound script and a simple trigger.
3. Sharing a document with a bound script and an installable trigger.

#### 1. Sharing a simple script

If you create a script that, for example, sends an email using `sendEmail` method.

```js
GmailAppsendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
```

And then share it with someone, that someone will have to authorize the script and then will be able to run it. When they do, the email will be sent as themselves, since they are the ones running the script. The script runs from their account.

#### 2. Sharing a document with a bound script and a simple trigger.

Say for example you have a sheet with an `onEdit` simple trigger. All you did was write:

```js
function onEdit() {
  console.log("Hello")
}
```

In the script editor. Then you share the sheet with someone else. That someone will be able to open the sheet and edit a range. Then the onEdit function will run from their account.

The simple `onEdit` is very limited however, it is not allowed to call things like `GmailApp` or anything that requires authorization to do.

#### 3. Sharing a document with a bound script and an installable trigger.

If you do have a function like:

```js
function sendMail(){
    GMailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
}
```

Then you **install** a trigger to run this function every time a form is submitted, for example, then it doesn't matter who you have shared it with, who has filled the form or otherwise, it will *always* run from the account that installed the trigger. So the email will always be from your account.

#### Workaround

It depends what you are trying to do exactly, but I think the best thing for you to do is to deploy your form and script as a Web App.

This will involve you creating your form in HTML. Here is a short example of a web app that is a form that will accept an email address and send an email to that address from the account that is accessing the form.

1. Open a new script project.
2. In `code.gs` paste:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("form")
}

function sendEmail(address){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(address, "Sent from right account", "Hello!")
}
```

3. Then create a new HTML file and call it `form`.
4. In the newly created file paste:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="my-form">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
      <label for="email">Recipient Email:</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    </form>

    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    const form = document.getElementById("my-form")
    const button = document.getElementById("submit")
    button.addEventListener('click', handleFormSubmit)

    function handleFormSubmit(e) {
      const form = document.getElementById("my-form")

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).sendEmail(form.email.value)

    }

    function success() {
      console.log("success")
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

5. Go to the "Deploy" button at the top right (if you are using the new editor), and select New Deployment.
6. Select type, "Web app". Execute as "User accessing the web app". Who has access "Anyone with Google account".
7. Click "Deploy".
8. Grant permissions.
9. You should get a URL, which you can share with anyone with a Google account. The website at the URL is a simple form. If you add in an email address in the last box, then the script will send an email as the logged in user.

Let me know if any of this is not clear and I will explain further.

#### References

- [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)